# How to delete a file permanently with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, filesystems, fs

I need to create a function in NodeJS that permanently deletes temporary files (instead of just deleting the normal way and storing the deleted files in the trash). In fact, my program will create a lot of temporary files and eventually the server's hard drive will get full very fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fs.unlink(path, callback)` will delete a file. As with all the fs methods, there's also the synchronous version, `fs.unlinkSync(path)`.

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlink_path_callback

Answer (score 0):

Using `unlink` (with callback) /`unlinkSync` in `fs` module.

```js
const fs = require('fs')

fs.unlinkSync(__dirname + 'yourfile.name')
```